# How to select rows after using row_number() in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have to select the null values one by one from a column with some null values in it. I have to select them one by one because I want to update all of them with different values.

I chose to do it with row_number() after running out of possible options in my mind, So here is the query that I executed

```
select cid, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY random()) as row from aa_dev.calls where cid is null;
```

[image: See result of above query]

How can I pick each row without storing it in any temp table and update each row?
This column has 100 values 96 are populated with integers with only 4 nulls.

I need to populate row_number as follows. for example there are total 10 values in this data and 3 of them are null values.

| cid | row |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 54 | 0 |
| null | 1 |
| 26 | 0 |
| 86 | 0 |
| 45 | 0 |
| null | 2 |
| 56 | 0 |
| null | 3 |
| 5 | 0 |

Comment: So, you just want to fill all NULL records with some random data? Please show us some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: You could take a look at the system-column ctid: SELECT ctid FROM aa_dev.calls WHERE cid IS NULL; It will point at the physical location for this record

Comment: @S-Man I have added a table in the question. That's my expected output

Comment: @FrankHeikens but that's going to select all null values, I want to select it one by one.

Comment: @S-Man  Also yes I want to fill all null records with some random data, but I don't want to update all of the null records at a time. I want to do it iteratively. So that I have control over what I have to insert in each null record.

Comment: That's not how SQL works. If you want to do it one record after another you have to execute one query after another, maybe from your backend. But than you are able to parse the NULL values over there... So not SQL magic is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways came to mind:

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cecd5773721094ef37da8268e31ad8d8)

Using the `row_number()` over partitions which are `(cid = NULL)` and `(cid != NULL)`. And this just execute for those records that are `NULL`, all others are set to `0`:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE WHEN cid IS NULL THEN
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cid IS NULL)
    ELSE 0 END
FROM
    mytable
```

Second way is simply using a `UNION` construct over `(cid = NULL)` and `(cid != NULL)`:

```
SELECT
    cid,
    row_number() OVER ()
FROM mytable
WHERE cid IS NULL

UNION

SELECT
   cid,
   0
FROM mytable
WHERE cid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Solved my problem.